# By the end of Batman v Superman, is there any use or need of secret identities?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

It seems there is no secret that hasn't been shared with multiple characters in B v S, including lots of non-heroes. Most of the principles, including human civilians, are up to speed on who is actually whom. Why the disassembling of the secret identity meme?

Comment: Maybe it was ridiculous that no one can recognize Clark Kent just because he's not wearing glasses?

Comment: Yes. How did any writer think that would work (before the super-hypnosis explanation, anyway)?

Comment: Can you point out exactly who does know? At the moment you're saying `"most ... principles, including ... civilians"` know, but I don't remember any public announcement of the secret identities. In fact, the funeral at the end happened for both characters simultaneously; if it was public knowledge, then they would have coalesced into funeral.

Comment: @Mooz Perry White knows when Lois asks for a chopper to Gotham. And spoiler alert!! Bet most everyone will put 2 and 2 together if Superman is resurrected and Clark Kent reappears at the Planet. Hard to brush off a pair of funerals as Oopsy's.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite & VBartilucci  And how does one have 2 funerals with only one body, some cups and balls trick? Just a memorial for the Man of Steel and a quick slight of hand by Batman who delivers Clark to a Smallville mortuary where the mortician just can't to his usual thing with this one particular corpse? Mrs. Kent goes all minimalist with no preparation or autopsy for her vigorous, health issue free, son with no medical records to speak of, who is dead? OK, No Problem, get a box. Come on now, who wouldn't ask some very basic questions before they said goodbye to their license? Died of?

Comment: @IhorSypko Perry White allowing Lois to go to Gotham has nothing to do with him knowing whether Clark is Superman or not. She asked so he sent her. He knows that she's got some sort of affinity with Superman, and when she rushes into a meeting, says she needs a chopper, he doesn't bat an eye-lid to stop her. However, he gives no indication (IMO) that this has anything to do with Clark.

Comment: @Mooz Perry initially doesn't agree to the chopper, he offers other options and finally agrees and the look on his face, his expression, acknowledges that Lois has a secret that Perry has uncovered and deduced. And the down-voting of a question about a main plot element seems incongruous everybody.

Answer (score 7):

The only person that knows for sure the identities of ALL the heroes is Lex Luthor, and presumably he's not of clear enough mind to share the information.  Clark knows who Batman is - how that occurs is not clear, but x-ray vision seems a likely possibility. Batman clearly does not know who Superman is, or he'd have said something right there when they met at Lex's party. Batman has data on Flash, Aquaman and Cyborg, but it's not clear he's yet read the data to the degree that he knows their identity, but he will clearly know enough to contact them by the time of the next film.

The general public has no idea who they are - certainly the government or the military do not.

As for how Superman can pass for Clark Kent, the most obvious is that there are seven billion people in the world, and many people resemble each other, and not everyone is that famous person.  There was actually an experiment done by Henry Cavill himself recently - he walked about Times Square in glasses, and nobody recognized him. This is because there was no expectation they'd see him there, so nobody was looking.  It probably wouldn't work at, say, Comic-Con.  Though Hugh Jackman walked around dressed as Wolverine, and was not recognized.

Comment: I remember Clark knowing who batman is because he could overhear his earpiece at Lex's party. Or maybe that was just the first clue.

Comment: By the *end* of the movie, it's clear that the 3 Justice League people know each other (Bruce and Diana -- out of costume -- are at Clark's grave). Since Lois was also there, it's logical to assume she's clued in as well...

Comment: _"Batman clearly does not know who Superman is, or he'd have said something right there when they met at Lex's party."_ I don't buy this at all. After all, Clark didn't say anything about Bruce. By your logic, since you reckon Clark knew about Bruce, he'd have known Bruce was Batman therefore he would have said something right there when they met.

Comment: _"certainly the government or the military do not"_ What makes you "certain" about this?

Comment: And as for Cavill's little trick, well sorry but Henry Cavill IRL is not even fractionally as famous as Superman is in the fictional world. Not even marginally, microscopically close! You do touch on this yourself with the Wolverine comment. Remember, for as much money as these films make, comic book/movie fans are a tiiiiiny proportion of the world's population. I don't think I know anyone else in my entire company who could even _name_ more than Superman and Batman.

Comment: +1 for the last bit.  In fact, if you look into popular celebrity encounters by people, some of them are actually harder to recognize than you think, because they're not "in character" while out in the public.  People like Rowan Atkinson and Jim Carrey do NOT behave like their comic stand-ups in public.

Comment: I agree with @Lightness Races in Orbit's comment. Superman is far more famous than Henry Cavill. A better analogy would be Barack Obama. How many Americans do you think would miss Obama just because he was wearing glasses? Or Donald Trump? Also, how long was Henry Cavill walking around? Superman has to go to his job every day.

Comment: Bet the government knows because that Martha Kent woman seems to be at the wrong place at the wrong time too often. And a long way from Kansas where Zod did a dance in Smallville.. 'Why's that?' asks some rookie agent or investigator who also notes that she has a son named Clark... 2+2=... Maybe Phil Coulson will formulate a scenario to share.

Comment: [Here's a video of Henry explaining what he did at Time's Square on Jimmy Kimmel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rho-OdAxvV8)